# Linear animation on HTML5 Canvas using KineticJS.How to make?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am developing an HTML5 canvas based mini-game and I can't seem to organize linear animation.

I am using this code for adding a "target" object to the canvas:

```
var target = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.drawImage(images.target, x, y, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x, y, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    context.closePath();
});
gameLayer.add(target);
```

I need to animate this object with linear animation, trying this code:

```
var mx = x;
setInterval(function(){
   mx -= 1;
   target.setPosition(mx, y);
   gameLayer.draw();
}, 500);
```

But, it didn't work! What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work, but I found the way to do as:

```
var mx = x;
var my = target.y;
target.transitionTo({
   x: mx,
   y: my,
   rotation: 0,
   scale: {x: 1, y: 1},
   duration: 1, //time to transition in second
});
```

You can see more details at: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-linear-transition-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0):

They have an Animation function. So you can

```
var myAnimationName = new Kinetic.Animation(function (frame) {
    console.log(frame.time);
    target.setX(target.getX() + 1);
    if (target.getX() < somePosition) {
        target.setX(somePosition);
        this.stop();
    }
}, layer);
myAnimationName.start();
```

You can use also `frame.time` if needed